# UTF8 support in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, azure, azure-sql-database

I read that need to use "nvarhar" for utf8 fields. But how to define it through Hibernate & Spring?

```
@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
private String title;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this change globally you can override the hibernate default mapping using the hibernate type registry: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-registry

Comment: I just have a different dialect. And he did everything automatically http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.ru/2014/04/how-to-change-varchar-to-nvarchar-in.html#.VQMar0twvQg